# After chang the content to button the button dose not work Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have  problem when I change the div td tag content to a tag the a tag dose not working after I clicked it same with input
this is the td tag

```
<td class='column2' id='e" . $row["id"] . "'>
        <a class='link' state='" . $row["id"] . ",".$_SESSION["id"]."'> 
           <span data-content='Enroll'> 
               Enroll
           </span>
        </a>
    </td>
<td class='column3' id='d" . $row["id"] . "'>
</td>
```

this is my JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("input").click(function(){
                alert("in");
                var StateName = $(this).attr("state");
                var classID = parseInt(StateName.substring(0, StateName.indexOf(",")));
                var ID = parseInt(StateName.substring(StateName.indexOf(",")+1));
                var e = "#e"+classID;
                var d = "#d"+classID;
                var Enrollbutton = "<a class='link' state='" + classID + "," + ID + "'> <span data-content='Enroll'> Enroll</span></a>";
                $.post("Drop.php",
                       { Drop: classID, 
                         ID: ID
                       },
                       function(data , state){
                           if(state){
                                alert("The class droped successfuly");
                                $(d).html("");
                                $(e).html("");
                                $(e).append(Enrollbutton);
                            }else{
                                alert("The class does not Droped successfuly");
                            }
                        });
            });
            $("a").click(function() {
                var StateName = $(this).attr("state");
                var classID = parseInt(StateName.substring(0, StateName.indexOf(",")));
                var ID = parseInt(StateName.substring(StateName.indexOf(",")+1));
                var e = "#e"+classID;
                var d = "#d"+classID;
                var dropbutton = "<div class='outer'><div class='inner'><label><input type='submit' value ='Drop' class='drop' state='"+classID+","+ID+"'></label></div></div>";
                $.post("Enroll.php",
                       { Enroll: classID, 
                         ID: ID
                       },
                       function(data , state){
                           if(state){
                                alert("The class Enrolled successfuly");
                                $(e).html("");
                                $(e).append("Enrolled");
                                $(d).append(dropbutton);
                            }else{
                               alert("The class does not Enrolled successfuly"); 
                            }
                        });
            });                
        });
```

I am a beginner in JQuery and search for this problem but found nothing so I wish you could help me thanks for all

Comment: do you mean the anchor tag? document ready only runs when the document loads so this means that the event handlers get registered only when the document loads... if you add new tags you need to bind their event handlers after you add the tags

Comment: How do I bind it? sorry I am new to JQuery :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need to set up delegated events so that if an element with an event listener is changed the event listener would still be present.

Change:

```
$("a").click(<fn>);
```

To:

```
$("table").on("click", "a", <fn>); //this assumes table element remains intact
//OR
$(document).on("click", "a", <fn>);
```

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to indicate you found the answer useful by clicking "^". Enjoy.